# Setting Font in CGBitmapContext.SelectFont using variable

Tags: iphone, macos, xamarin.ios, monomac

I'm trying to write a general purpose routine that will set the font using a variable instead of the literal font name.

```
CGBitmapContext.SelectFont(fontName, fontSize, CGTextEncoding.MacRoman);
```

instead of:

```
CGBitmapContext.SelectFont("Arial", fontSize, CGTextEncoding.MacRoman);
```

But it seems not to work. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Rick

Comment: It's a bit surprising. Could you provide a small test case so we can duplicate this ? thanks

Comment: context.SelectFont(iconStyle.topTextFont, iconStyle.topTextFontSize, CGTextEncoding.MacRoman); - Does not work. I have to use "Arial" instead of topTextFont variable, which is set to "Arial"...

Answer (score 0):

Please post a more complete sample, the following code works for me:

```
context.SetFillColor (0.0f, 1.0f);
context.SelectFont ("Arial", 28, CGTextEncoding.MacRoman);
context.ShowTextAtPoint (pageRect.GetMidX (), pageRect.GetMidY (), "Hello Select Font (string)");
string font = "Arial";
context.SelectFont (font, 28, CGTextEncoding.MacRoman);
context.ShowTextAtPoint (pageRect.GetMidX (), pageRect.GetMidY () + 40, "Hello Select Font (var)");
```

Both lines uses Arial and it still works if I switch them (using the var first).

Comment: huh ? not in the first SelectFont call (line #2) for comparison purpose but I did use the 'font' variable (defined in line #4) in the second call (line #5). Both results are visually identical - except the text inside () of course.